# Get the first element that the mouse hovered after a MouseLeave event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

Using jQuery/Javascript, how can I check which was the first element that the mouse hovered after a `MouseLeave` event?

Basically, I want to check from an array of elements if the mouse is rolling over those elements or not.

I'm trying to use the `event.relatedTarget`.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists a [`relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget) property on the mouse events

> The `MouseEvent.relatedTarget` read-only property is the secondary target for the mouse event, if there is one

and for the `mouseleave` it points to the element that was entered.

So you could just do

```
$('element').mouseleave(function(event){
    // assuming that allowedList holds the array of allowed elements
    if ( allowedList.indexOf( event.relatedTarget ) > -1 ){
        // found
    } else {
        // not found
    }
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/V4pJb/

Comment: This is was exactly what i was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can do this:

```
​$("#foo").mouse​​​leave(function(e) {
    var element = $(e.target);
})​;​
```

Here's a working example. You can mouse over the text "Hello" and on mouseout, it will tell you which element it is leaving.
http://jsfiddle.net/k7Gfv/

If the mouseenter (or hover) is different from the mouseleave, then you'll need to track this using a variable. On mouseenter (or hover), set a variable that will store that element. On mouseleave, you can then reference that variable (just remember to clear or reset the value for the next time the mouseenter even is fired).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for, but maybe it's somehing like this:

```
var elements = $("#a1, #a2");

$("#a3").on('mouseleave', nextElm);

function nextElm() {
    $('div').on('mouseenter', thisIsIt);
    $("#r").html('Now hover another element ?');   
}

function thisIsIt(e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.target, elements)!=-1){
        $("#r").html('yes');
    }else{
        $("#r").html('no');            
    }
    $("#a3").off('mouseleave', nextElm);
    $('div').off('mouseenter', thisIsIt);
}
```

​

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zB7UF/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6j8SR/2/)

```
var hovered = false;;
$('div').mouseleave(function(e) {
    hovered = true;
});
$('div').hover(function(ev) {
        if (hovered) {
            alert(ev.target);
            hovered = false;
        }
});
​
```